# Unable to find 'coordinates' in GeoJSON string error when creating controller API

Tags: postgis, geojson, node-js

I am trying to create an API to insert Geojson data into Postgres/PostGIS and I am getting the below error message when I try to make a post. Is there anything obvious that stands out where I could be going wrong?

Could this be something to do with installing PostGis incorrectly?

```
{
    "message": "The 'coordinates' in GeoJSON are not an array"
}
```

geojson POST in Postman

```
{
    "diveSchoolName": "Raja Ampat Dive Center",
    "diveSchoolLocation": "Raja Ampat, Indonesia",
    "diveRegionID": 5,
    "certificatesID": 1,
    "diveSpotID": 7,
    "diveSchoolGeo": {
      "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-0.2333324, 130.5166646]
        }    
    }
}
```

controller API

```
exports.createDiveSchool = async (req, res) => {

        diveSchool.create({
            diveSchoolName: req.body.diveSchoolName,
            diveSchoolLocation: req.body.diveSchoolLocation,
            diveRegionID: req.body.diveRegionID,
            certificatesID: req.body.certificatesID,
            diveSpotID: req.body.diveSpotID,
            diveSchoolGeo: {type: "Point", coordinates: req.body.diveSchoolGeo},
        })
            .then((diveSchool) => {
                res.status(200).json({
                    statusCode: 200,
                    success: true,
                    message: "Success",
                    diveSchool: diveSchool
                });
            })
                .catch((err) => {
                    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
                });
        };
```

diveSchool model

```
diveSpotID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        diveSchoolGeo: {
            type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT'),
            allowNull: false
        },
        userID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        }},
        {
```

Comment: Can't test, so no answer yet; in the controller, in `diveSchoolGeo: {type: "Point", coordinates: req.body.diveSchoolGeo}` you are passing the complete GeoJSON feature rather than just the coordinate array.

Comment: How do I pass just the coordinate array? Do I remove the feature line from the Postman JSON? I have tried this before. I already have the properties set-up in the other columns.

Comment: Well, I'd say either `diveSchoolGeo: req.body.diveSchoolGeo` or `diveSchoolGeo: {type: "Point", coordinates: req.body.diveSchoolGeo.geometry.coordinates}`